# router = useRouter(); in Setup(). But then how can I access to the router object in my methods?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

As you know, if I do this :

```
const router = useRouter();
```

in one of the methods, I got and undefined object. So I need to put it in the setup():

```
setup()
{
     const router = useRouter();
}
```

But then, how can I use the router object in my methods? My method will do the router.push(). How can the router object be accessible in my methods ?

Thanks

Comment: Which methods? There are no `methods` methods in composition api. You can use `router` in the scope of setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can mix composition API and options API. I will propose it as a solution, and not as a recommendation. I used it when migrating my apps from options API to composition API. Evidently, if you are starting from scratch it is best to stick to one of them.

So, the trick is to return the router in setup(), then it becomes available as an instance property.

```
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter();

    return {
      router,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    navigateTo(route) {
      this.router.push(route);
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function inside of `setup()` and then call it.

An example:

```js
const router = useRouter()
    
function pushQuery() {
  router.push({...})
}
```

```js
<button @click="pushQuery">Push Query</button>
```